# How can I run multiple filters in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I want to run multiple filters on different columns like 'Frequency', 'Decile' and 'Audience' as 'all' and 'Dimension' = 'campaign' and KPI name='honda_2018...' from an excel sheet imported in pandas. I am running the following code:

```py
def filter_df(df, *args):
    for 'Frequency', 'All' in args:
        df = df[df['Frequency'] == 'All']
    return df
```

It is giving me an error `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`. Please help

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with the desired output; then it will be easier to help.

Comment: you can't use strings in `for`-loop this way. You can only do `for variable in ['Frequency', 'All']`

Comment: maybe write all filters manually without `for`-loop.

Comment: @tamalika : Please do format the question correctly using the guidelines , specially the code block and provide the  input and output expected so that we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.loc`

Sample Data:

```
my_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'name' : ['alex5','martha1','collin4','cynthia9'],
                              'simulation1':[71,4.8,65,4.7],
                              'simulation2':[71,4.8,69,4.7],
                              'simulation3':[70,3.8,68,4.9],
                              'experiment':[70.3,3.5,65,4.4]})
my_frame
```

Running this code below will return the index [1,2,3]:

```
my_frame.loc[(my_frame["simulation1"] == 4.8)]
```

Then if you want to filter more column use `&`, this code below will return index [2,3]:

```
my_frame.loc[(my_frame["simulation1"] == 4.8) &  \
             (my_frame["simulation2"] == 69)
            ]
```

Rinse and repeat until you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it's possible

```
df = df[df['Frequency'] == 'All' and df['Something'] == 'Something else']
```